# Can I use xna tutorials to learn monogame?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Can I use xna tutorials to learn monogame? I can't find any good monogame tutorials but there are tons of xna tutorials available and from what I have seen they are pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The MonoGame API is intended to be exactly the same as XNA. In most cases this is entirely true. If MonoGame doesn't work just like XNA it's usually considered a bug.

The exception to the rule is the way the [Content Pipeline](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Pipeline) works. Although, once you get your head around it things are fairly similar.